# MYSQL workbench - tables location

Tags: mysql-workbench

This might sound rudimentary but, I have created tables by running queries in Workbench . Now, where are those tables stored on my computer ? Where does workbench stores them ?

Comment: I am using windows 7   .... Mysql workbench 5.2 ce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows 7, your files should be under `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\<your MySQL version>\Data\`

Comment: ProgramData is probably a hidden folder. Were you able to find it?

Comment: How about for Mac OS?  Any idea where the default folder is?